# where could i get jWebSocketTCPEngine-1.0.jar

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

i get this error when i start my tomcat server.

```
2014-04-17 11:18:11,907 WARN  - JWebSocketConfig: jWebSocketTCPEngine-1.0.jar not found at C:/jWebSocket-1.0/libs/jWebSocketTCPEngine-1.0.jar.
2014-04-17 11:18:11,907 ERROR - JWebSocketXmlConfigInitializer: jWebSocket engine class org.jwebsocket.tcp.TCPEngine could not be loaded.
```

i download jWebSocketServer-1.0-b30518.zip from offical website. i cannot found it in %JWEBSOCKET_HOME%\libs.

where could i get that jar file.

thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am. Other jars could be found.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I think tcp engine is bundled with `jWebSocketServer-1.0.jar`. I was found tcp engine class when I inspect above mentioned jar with `jd` gui tool. can you look at that jar and assure that classes related to tcp engine is inside that jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the engine definition found in `jWebSocket.xml`

```
<engine>
    <name>org.jwebsocket.tcp.TCPEngine</name>
    <id>tcp0</id>
    <jar>jWebSocketTCPEngine-1.0.jar</jar><!--change this since tcp class is in jWebSocketServer-1.0.jar-->
    <port>8787</port>
    <sslport>9797</sslport>
    <keystore>${JWEBSOCKET_HOME}conf/jWebSocket.ks</keystore>
    <password>jWebSocket</password>
    <domains>
      <domain>*</domain>
    </domains>
    <timeout>0</timeout>
    <maxframesize>1048840</maxframesize>
    <maxconnections>10000</maxconnections>
    <onmaxconnections>reject</onmaxconnections>
    <settings>
      <setting key="workers">50</setting>
      <setting key="writer_timeout">1000</setting>
    </settings>     
</engine>
```

according to that it tries to load TCPEngine class from `jWebSocketTCPEngine-1.0.jar`. As I can see that class is in `jWebSocketServer-1.0.jar`. so change the jar definition in `jWebSocketServer-1.0.jar` as

```
 <jar>jWebSocketServer-1.0.jar</jar>
```

and make sure you downloaded the jWebSocket Server from [jWebSocket Latest Versions](https://jwebsocket.org/downloads/jwebsocket-latest-versions)

Comment: `<!--change this since tcp class is in jWebSocketServer-1.0.jar-->` I cannot see this words other places. Did you comment this words?

Comment: I added that line to indicate the line that need to be change

Comment: i see.Did you startup jWebSocketServer in standalone mode before?  `jWebSocketTCPEngine-1.0.jar` is ok.I don't understand why.

Comment: no. but I read the documentation and found it needs tcp engine to start and it include in jWebSocketServer jar. that's why I told you to change the jar definition in that xml. did that solve your problem?

Comment: It doesn't work.                                                            `2014-04-17 15:56:56,834 DEBUG - JWebSocketXmlConfigInitializer: Loading engine 'org.jwebsocket.tcp.TCPEngine' from 'C:/jWebSocket-1.0/libs/jWebSocketServer-1.0.jar'...
2014-04-17 15:56:56,848 ERROR - JWebSocketXmlConfigInitializer: Error initializing engine based on given configuration. Make sure that you are using correct jar file or engine class is in the classpath
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jwebsocket.tcp.TCPEngine.<init>(org.jwebsocket.api.EngineConfiguration)`

Comment: when I started it in standalone mode it gives me no error. but you got these errors in tomcat server.isn't it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50851/discussion-between-lakshman-and-ron)

Comment: I'm getting same JWebSocketXmlConfigInitializer: Loading engine 'org.jwebsocket.tcp.TCPEngine' from 'C:/jWebSocket-1.0/libs/jWebSocketServer-1.0.jar'... 2014-04-17 15:56:56,848 ERROR - JWebSocketXmlConfigInitializer: Error initializing engine based on given configuration. Make sure that you are using correct jar file or engine class is in the classpath java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jwebsocket.tcp.TCPEngine.<init>(org.jwebsocket.api.EngineConfiguration)